# Javascripts in html file included using ng-include does not execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-inculde to include an html file that aslo includes some javascript codes for that page, but the javascripts are not executed,

here is my Code :

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title ng-cloak>{{Page.Title}}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/swiper.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/style.css">
  <link href="/media/css/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/media/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/media/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/ng-device-detector.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/re-tree.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/angular-md5.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/angular-cache.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my home.html page:

```
<p>Welcome, this is the home page!!</p>
<div ng-include src="'/template/include/home_s.html'"></div>
```

And this is my home_s.html:

```
<script>
  console.log("Selam, chooni khasi?");
  alert("Sellam, choooni?");
</script>
```

Comment: Try with `<div ng-include="/template/include/home_s.html"></div>`.

Comment: I've tried that too! didn't help

Comment: Your javascript files are loaded using relative references.  Is it possible that the relative references are breaking because the include is from a relative subfolder of home.html?  Have you confirmed that the javascript files load correctly in the browser?

Comment: Yes, javascript file is loaded correctly, but is not running!! why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
<ng-include src="'/template/include/home_s.html'"></ng-include>
```

Or:

```
<div ng-include="'/template/include/home_s.html'"></div>
```

However, Angular on its own doesn't support loading scripts inside templates. For this to work you need to include jQuery (make sure you load it before Angular).

**Demo without jQuery**: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh27ArEyIk53VRB7e61C?p=preview

**Demo with jQuery**: http://plnkr.co/edit/TxOmx5ksEFC2larJiJBA?p=preview